# How to auto fit ImageView in ScrollView as Screen Height as

Tags: android, android-layout

I use ScrollView with multiple Views but I have an ImageView on the top. What I need is auto fitting image height as screen height as.

My current layout starts like this :

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/layout_dashboard"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <include
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        layout="@layout/toolbar_dashboard_layout" />
    <ScrollView
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

Thanks.

Comment: I think that the only way to achieve this is to set `ImageView` height from code based on container height.

Answer (score 2):

To make sure `ImageView` adjusts its height, use attribute `adjustViewBounds` for example:

```
<ImageView android:id="..." 
  android:adjustViewBounds="true" ... />
```

Comment: I use that attribute but it is not related with my problem. I want to fill screen with Image View but inside Scroll View

Comment: have you got the solution to this?  @user3817558

Answer (score 0):

Your screen dimensions cannot be known in a resource file, as the Android system takes these files and *then* renders them to the given device screen.

So, to make any View proportional to the screen size, we need to set its parameters programmatically. Luckily, Android gives us [Display](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html), which holds data about our display. Use this object to retrieve the height of the display, then set the height of our View to that:

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view);
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();

//We need to store the dimensions in a Point object.
Point point = new Point();
display.getSize(point);

//Now, set the width and height.
profileImage.getLayoutParams().width = point.x;
profileImage.getLayoutParams().height = point.y;
```